# Why do we expresss a vector coplanar to two others as a combination of those vectors and their cross product?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Vector Algebra, a vector coplanar with two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ can be expressed as a combination of $\vec{a}$ , $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{a} \times \vec {b}$ (cross product) . Why is this?

Comment: It can't, only as combination of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$

Comment: in 3D, given that $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are independent, then **any  vector** can be expressed in the way you show: if coplanar, then the coefficient of the crossproduct will be null

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb R^3$, if $a,b$ define a plane in their span, then they are linearly independent. Depending on your definition of cross product, it is immediate that $a \times b$ is perpendicular to the plane, annd thus $\{a,b,a \times b\}$ give three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ so they define a basis. From this, you can gather that any vector in $\mathbb R^3$ is a linear combination of these three vectors.

On the other hand, if some vector is on the plane, then it **must** be a linear combination of $a,b$ (if they are not the same up to scaling.)

To see this, think about what a plane *is*: $ax+by+cz=0$ after translation, so given two vectors $a,b$, we can see that two different unit vectors are enough to determine the plane.